# A script to identify whether a file descriptor has gone bad

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, socket, netbsd

**Problem** : I have a server program running which connects to a remote program using TCP sockets. There many of them (say 20). My problem is one of the socket descriptor has gone bad and has recieved EOF. But due to bug in program it never closes it but adds it back to select() set and causes unnecessary pain.

**What I did to find it** : I attached to DDB, and called read(fd,..) to each of them. The bad descriptor returned 0 and I tapped it there.

Though this worked for me, but had a cost of wasting bytes from other sockets and the other functions may behave wrongly.

**What I am looking for** is to get an idea on a non-intrusive mechanism that solves my purpose without affecting the running programs.

By the way my NetBSD system understands tcsh only.

Comment: Is fixing the program to detect this condition an option?

Comment: Yeah I did so :) - But I have faced many other similar issues. Just got an idea of using recv(fd,..,MSG_PEEK) which should be ok.

Comment: It's hard for an external processus to detect this kind of condition on file descriptors. The only way I can think of is using an attached process (as you did apparently) but that's not really a solution, especially for a running server.

Comment: Your NetBSD system also understands /bin/sh, and /bin/ksh.

Comment: You can't script DDB (yet -- there's work occurring to add Lua support to DDB though).

Comment: Also, using DDB to debug user processes is a losing game -- the system is otherwise dead when DDB is active.

Answer (score 0):

In BSD derived systems the canonical way to investigate the open file descriptors in another running process is to use the `fstat`(1) command (using the `-p` option to specify the process ID of interest).

From the `fstat` output it may be possible to tell if the peer has closed a TCP connection.

However if the problem is actually a bug in a program you have source for then you should probably just compile it with `-g` and debug it using a proper user-level debugger, such as the natively supplied `gdb`.